# Configuring Python setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fortran, f2py

I have created a project called [NumerMP](https://github.com/EverLookNeverSee/numermp) a few days ago which will provide multi-threaded numerical methods (using OpenMP library), and will provide python API for end users (using wrapper functons-f2py). I had to use [f2py smart way](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/f2py.getting-started.html#the-smart-way), due to customizing fortran signature files (.pyf) before generating extension modules. To do so I ran commands below:

- `python  -m  numpy.f2py  trial_file.f90  -m  module_name  -h  trial_file.pyf`
- `python  -m  numpy.f2py  -c  --f90flags=’-fopenmp’  -lgomp  trial_file.pyf  trial_file.f90`

Then I tested generated  extension modules (.so files) inside package itself and they worked correctly, Then I built whole project and uploaded to test pypi and installed it using pip, But I got an ImportError.

The structure of the package is as follows:
[image]

When I run each sample wrapper function inside package itself, as you can see they run correctly.
But I got error below when I used it inside other project:
[image]

Comment: You should show your error, and the commands that produced it, and the caommands when it fworked. But I suspect it's related to linking, you might not have the same libraries installed or found. Also you might need the `-fPIC` flag.

Comment: I edited the post with useful information.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text.

Comment: You should actually "package" the code: use `from numpy.distutils.core import setup, Extension`. Something along `m1 = Extension('numermp.equations.first', sources = [ 'numermp/equations/first.f90' ] , extra_compile_args=['PUT EXTRA COMPILE ARGS HERE'])` adapted to your options.

Answer (score 0):

Update

You have some sibling submodules:

```
module
|- first
|   |- functions.py
|- second
|   |- wrapper.py
```

Then in second/wrappdr.py:

```
from ..first import functions

functions.function1()
```

Comment: What are **package1** and **package2** in this case?

Comment: the dependencies of your project

Comment: This will not help. The module not being found is one that is part of the package.